# php increment variable with onclick

Tags: php, onclick

I want to use the function onclick to increment a variable [increment the variable paid]

paid is by default at 0 i want to increment at 1.

I try this code : onclick='paid++'   but is not working...

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5t14.png)

```
foreach($query as $index=>$row) {
    echo ($colorCount++%2) ? "<tr class='alt'>" : "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='" . getPaidColor($row['paid']) . "' onclick='paid++ '></td>";
    echo "<td class='" . getDelayColor($row['hour']) . "' onclick='postDeleteForm(" . $index . ")'></td>";
    foreach($columns as $column) {
        echo "<td>" . $row[$column] . "</td>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `paid` defined?

Comment: What did you tried onclick is html event it will fire something that was implemented using JavaScript.

Comment: is this paid variable is js or php?

Comment: The Variable is php it's define in my sql database